# Face Problem while uploading upto 100MB files

Tags: php

I am having a problem while uploading upto 100mb files in PHP. less then 100mb file working fine.

In php.ini file. i set these value

```
upload_max_filesize 500M
post_max_size 800M
max_execution_time 1200
memory limit 1000M
```

we not see any error on my log error file. can any please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: Did you restart your server after making the changes in `php.ini`? Did you edit the correct `php.ini` for your server and not for CLI? Have you checked `phpinfo()` that your values are properly set?

Comment: yes restart and also same detail show in phpinfo()

Comment: What HTTP server do you use? E.g. Apache allows also to restrict the max. upload size. Google for LimitRequestBody.

Comment: i use Apache server